# ¿Cómo cambiar el idioma de los mensajes de validación en formularios web?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net

Desarrollo una aplicación en la cual valido campos y me funciona bien, pero mi aplicación es multilenguaje y necesito cambiar el idioma en que se muestran dichos mensajes a inglés y portugués, ahora solo se muestran en español.

*¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?*

codigo HTML:

```
<div class="divEmail">
    <form id="form"  name="form">
        <div style="margin-left:10%;">
            <h4 class="text-success"> @Resources.IniciarSesion </h4>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="chxNoSoy" name="chxNosoy" class="btn btn btn-default active" required /> @Resources.NoSoyUnRobot </label>
        </div>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="@Resources.IngreseEmail" class="boxTxt form-control" required />
        <div style="height:6px;"></div>
        <input type="submit" id="sendMail" name="sendMail" value="@Resources.Enviar" class="btn btn-success voton" onclick="VerificarEmail()"/>
        <p style="font-size:smaller;">@Resources.AceptarCondicion</p>
    </form>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En qué tecnología estás trabajando esto? supongo que es AspNet Mvc por el "@Resources" ¿verdad?.

Comment: siii asi es ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `setCustomValidity` para aplicar un texto personalizado al html.

```
<input class="form-control" type="email" required="" 
    placeholder="username" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Texto personalizado')">
</input>
```

Para mas informacion de como usar las validaciones personalizadas https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/

Comment: Pruebo y te comento

Comment: @Sanchis, me parece que Efrain pregunta es, particularmente, sobre cómo "traducir" los mensajes y no de cómo utilizarlos.

Comment: @CamiloBernal  ups yo entendí que necesita traducir los mensajes nativos de los navegadores al poner required en sus inputs.

Comment: @EfrainMejiasC te funcionó?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que creo que te está pasando es que en tu archivo de recursos (Archivo con extensión .rex) tienes definidos tus términos en idioma español. Por eso ves los textos en español.

Lo ideal es que tengas un archivo de recursos por cada idioma a soportar. Cada uno con sus respectivas traducciones.

Para ello, si tu archivo de recursos principal se llama, por ejemplo, "Captions.rex" (Que tenga los textos en inglés, por ejemplo), tengas un archivo "Captions.es.rex" con los mismos textos pero en español, otro "Captions.fr.rex" con los mismos textos en francés y así sucesivamente.

Si estás trabajando con Visual Studio, hay varios complementos que te ayudan a traducir los archivos de recursos.

Comment: Alli los mensajes que se muestran no estan usando ningun tipo de traduccion desde el .resx

Comment: Al utilizar "@Resources.AceptarCondicion" estás obteniendo el texto desde  @Resources ¿no?. Si estoy equivocado, avísame y elimino la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

siguiendo el consejo de Sanchis agrege los siguientes eventos a los tags input:

```
oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Texto personalizado')" 
oninput="setCustomValidity('')"
```

Mi codigo quedo de la siguiente manera :

```
<div class="divEmail">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ResponseMessage", "Home")) 
    { 
        <div style="margin-left:10%;">
            <h4 class="text-success"> @Resources.IniciarSesion </h4>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="chxNoSoy" name="chxNosoy" class="btn btn btn-default active" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('@Resources.ChxRequerido')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" /> @Resources.NoSoyUnRobot </label>
        </div>
              <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="@Resources.IngreseEmail" class="boxTxt form-control" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('@Resources.EmailRequerido')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" /><br />
              <input type="submit" id="sendMail" name="sendMail" value="@Resources.Enviar" class="btn btn-success voton" />
     }
</div>
```